# Sequelize extend Model Class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am working on a legacy project that we would like to migrate to Typescript. It has models defined in the following format:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

class MyModel extends Sequelize.Model {
  public static init(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        field: "user_id"
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: "created_at"
      }
    };

    super.init(attributes, {
      sequelize
    });
  }
}

export default MyModel;
```

I would like to convert them to typescript without having to change the interface for consumers. By that I mean I want to extend `Sequelize.Model` and I want to define a `public static init` method.

I am getting the following error from Typescript on `Sequelize.Model`

```
Type 'Model<any, any>' is not a constructor function type.
```

And all of the research I've done points to using `Sequelize.define` to define models.

This being a legacy project I don't want to re-write all of my models just to conform to the types so I'm wondering how I can properly extend `Sequelize.Model`?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work in runtime? Which version of `sequelize` are you using?

Comment: @KarolMajewski - When it was pure JS it worked fine. When it's a `.ts` file it won't compile so I cannot test it at runtime. Im using `sequelize` 4.42.0 and `@types/sequelize` 4.27.33

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public static init(sequelize) {
    super.init.call(this,{ 
        id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        },  
        text: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(5000) // extra long length
        }  
    }, {
        sequelize: sequelize
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was just struggling with a similar problem myself, and this seems to work for me-

```
class MyModel extends Sequelize.Model {
    public static initialize(sequelize) {
        const attributes = {
            userId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "user_id"
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                field: "created_at"
            }
        };

        return this.init(attributes, {
            sequelize
        });
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed the static method as "initialize" instead of "init".